# Использование функции getche()

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь добиться от программы, чтобы она подсчитывала количество букв и слов. Visual Studio выводит ошибку, указывая на getche(). Хотя синтаксически, она используется правильно. В чем моя ошибка?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int chcount = 0;
    int wdcount = 1;
    char ch = 'a';
    cout << "Enter the string: ";
    while (ch != '\r')
    {
        ch = getche();
        if (ch = ' ')
            wdcount++;
        else
            chcount++;
    }
    cout << "\nWords " << wdcount << endl;
    cout << "Letters: " << (chcount - 1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что у неё нет такой функции... И вообще, какую именно ошибку?

Comment: @Qwertiy  'getche': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _getche. See online help for details.

Comment: Ну и используй `_getche`?

Comment: @Qwertiy Пробовал, после того, как ввожу строку, ничего больше не происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая ваша ошибка :) - нужно не

```
if (ch = ' ')
```

a

```
if (ch == ' ')
```

Вторая - если будут идти несколько пробелов подряд, вы их посчитаете словами...

Ну, а `getche()` ни при чем (да и, в общем-то, зря вы ее, нестандарт, используете...)

Comment: Я так понимаю, у него не компилируется?

Comment: А, всё, дошло...

Comment: @Harry вы случайно не знаете как в Visual Studio сделать так, чтобы консоль при завершении работы программы закрывалась не сразу?

Comment: Ну, обычно вставляется что-то, что ожидает нажатия клавиши. Распространенные варианты - `system("pause")`, `getchar()` или что-то аналогичное по действию. Словом, ожидание какого-то ввода пользователя.